# Promise not resolving when component render with $router.push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to to get socket ID when inside the mounted hook of the component. But when I refresh the page it works, not working when user enters in component with $router.push()

```
 getSocketId() {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    debugger;
                     Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('connected', function () {
                     resolve(Echo.socketId())
                 });
                })
        },
```

```
  mounted(){
     this.getSocketId().then((socketId => {
                  let data =  {
                      data : {
                          booking_id : this.$route.params.id,
                          user_id : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("app_user_data")).id,
                          is_active: 1
                      },
                      socket_id : socketId
                  }
                this.postUserDataToFirebolt(data)
                this.addUserInBooking(data)
            }))
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to set a key on your router-view

Comment: `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>`

Comment: I'm using Vue-router @Muhammad

Comment: Yes, I know that. If you go to your `App.vue` file, you will see a custom tag `<router-view>`. add the `:key="$route.fullPath"` there.